# Timestamp conversion to date, time and duration calculation

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have scheduled tasks table where I store scheduled task id, type, exec_time, end_time etc...

I get the exec/end time as timestamp.

For BI purposes I need to somehow calculate the duration (end_time - exec_time) and return it in hh:mm:ss.

The format of the exec/end_time is dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss:miliseconds o'clock.

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance!
Steve

Comment: Does `exec/end_time` really have "o'clock" at the end of it?

Comment: In standard SQL you can simply do `end_time - exec_time` (if both columns are properly defined as `TIMESTAMP`)  Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: bjones, yes they have in the original source data, tableau omits it.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, it's a system (Calypso) using Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this is in Tableau using a calculated field. This may not be as elegant as what you could do in the DBMS; however, it will work:

```
RIGHT("0" + STR(INT(DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) / 60)),2)
+ ":" +
RIGHT("0" + STR(INT((DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) % 6000) / 60)),2)
+ ":" +
RIGHT("0" + STR(INT((DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) % 600))),2)
```

"Duration" is the calculated field in my screenshot below:

[image]

**UPDATE** - per additional comment -

To make it a time *measure*:

```
MAKETIME(
   INT(DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) / 60),
   INT((DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) % 6000) / 60),
   INT((DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) % 600))
)
```

**ADDITIONAL DETAIL** - to address you subsequent questions `

If you are going to be doing any calculation with time, you should be using `date` or `numeric`. For example, since the smallest temporal unit you care about are seconds, you can use `DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time])` in your calculations that add or remove time (in seconds).
Alternatively, just use the built-in date functions `DATEADD`, `DATEDIFF`, and so on.

If you want to display the duration in this format `hh:mm:ss`, then you need to create a string, like I did above. The reason is because if the duration exceeds 24 hours, it is not something that will be properly represented just by a `time` element - since a whole day (or more) has passed.

In the above (very top) calculation, I left-pad the hours, minutes, and seconds with a '0', but select only the2 rightmost characters. This means that if a value is only a single-digit, then a 0 is added before. If the value is already 2-digits, it won't be changed int he result. So, `1` becomes `01`, but `13` stays `13`.

I highly recommend you play around with these solutions and test them to ensure you understand how they work.

Comment: I suppose you have calculated it in Tableau and it's calculated field: End time - exec time.

Comment: How can I turn it to be measure, rather dimension?

Comment: @Steve - I don't understand your first comment. For the second comment, you can, but you won't be able to rely on the date part of it. I'll update my answer to include that solution.

Comment: Can you please explain me why did you divide and did modulo 3 times?
INT will return integer value to maketime which will return it to be hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @Steve - "If the duration is 25 hours it will show it?" - No. Because 25 hours is not a valid hour for _time_.

Comment: Nicarus, how can I build a duration that will be a measure and will actually show me that the task run for 40 hours for example?
And what is the 0 for in your first comment? Why do you put it?

Comment: And the global goal is to be able to sum up the run times (durations) of each task. I am building some dashboards to show sum of runtime per task type (includes multiple task id's for each task type), after that I will dig into the task type that have highest time duration, go there and analyze what task did the problem and compare it to history and average run time of the task.

Comment: @Steve I want to help you, but it is a little hard to follow along in the comments. Could you append your additional questions to the original - maybe provide examples of desired output?

Comment: Nicarus, thank you very much for the help!
Let's start from the start point, I have the following data (other fields doesn't matter):
task id, task type, exec time, end time.
I need to build in Tableau a measure called duration.
This measure will calculate the amount of time task run in hh:mm:ss.
I need this to be a measure as I want to sum/substract and apply any other function on it.
Is it helping you to help me?

Comment: Another question is can you please explain why do you use 0 in the
RIGHT("0" + STR(INT(DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) / 60)),2) expression?

And why do you divide it by 60?
Also what is the explanation for the INT(DATEDIFF("second",[Exec Time],[End Time]) / 60)? What this expression do?

Comment: I was hoping you would edit your actual question (at the top) and append your additional questions to it. The comments second is bad for that. I added the '0' so that you would get '03:01:04' in the case where it the hours/minutes/seconds were single-digit numbers instead of '3:1:4'

Comment: Thanks, and in the case it is already 13:33:22 it will add zeros too?